# How do you create a 3-axis bar chart using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, charts, axes

Does anyone know how you can use Javascript libraries to create a 3-axis bar chart similar to this one?

[image]

Comment: Plotly.js can do that

Comment: Hi Jankapunkt, thank you for your response.  I cant' find any examples of a three-axis bar chart on plotly.js.